# I can't understand why do i have these two errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I keep getting 2 errors saying this:Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs(4,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

second one: Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs(24,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
Please help me because i'm new to unity and c#.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

{
   bool gameHasEnded = false;

   public float restartDelay = 1f;

   public void EndGame ()
   {
      if (gameHasEnded == false)
      {
          gameHasEnded = true;
          Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
          Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
      }
   }

    void Restart ()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well your class definition is missing .... you start with `{` but it should probably be `public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour {`

Comment: Thanks with this code it fixed one of the erros. But i still have this one: Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs(23,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Answer (score 2):

In C#, fields and methods are declared *inside a type*. You're missing that line:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

class GameManager // you may want a specific base-type or accessibility
{                 // for example, public class GameManager : SomeBaseType
   bool gameHasEnded = false;

   public float restartDelay = 1f;

   // etc
}
```

Comment: I would suggest editing `for example public class SomeType : SomeBaseType` into a more unity related types, so OP understands better

Comment: @bradbury9 well, I'm not a Unity person - but: looks like derHugo has me covered there

Comment: I just made it `GameManager` since the file is called `GameManager.cs`